How to Retrieve Shared Catalog Data by ID in Magento 2 Enterprise B2B?
I am currently working with Magento 2 Enterprise B2B version and I'm facing a challenge with shared catalogs. I need to retrieve shared catalog data using its ID.
Now how to correctly retrieve shared catalog data by its ID in Magento 2 Enterprise B2B? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Magento gives you the ability to maintain shared catalogs with the custom pricing structure for different companies.
You can get Shared Catalog data by shared catalog id programmatically.
Magento\SharedCatalog\Api\SharedCatalogRepositoryInterface Interface can be used to get, delete, and save  Shared catalog-related things.
<?php

class YourClass {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\SharedCatalog\Api\SharedCatalogRepositoryInterface $sharedCatalogRepository
    ) {
        $this->sharedCatalogRepository = $sharedCatalogRepository;
    }
 
    public function getSharedCatalog()
    {
        $sharedCatalogId = 1;
        $sharedCatalog = $this->sharedCatalogRepository->get($sharedCatalogId);
        print_r($sharedCatalog->debug(),true); //to debug shared catalog data
        return $sharedCatalog;
    }
}

You can then use it using by calling function $this->getSharedCatalog();
If you will print the output of the function it will return result like below.
[
    "entity_id" => "1",
    "name" => "Default (General)",
    "description" => "Default shared catalog",
    "customer_group_id" => "1",
    "type" => "1",
    "created_at" => "2023-05-16 11:55:38",
    "created_by" => "19",
    "store_id" => "0",
    "customer_group_code" => "Default (General)",
    "tax_class_id" => "3",
  ]

